# Why are Java EE 6 applications do not update interfaces real-time

Tags: java, java-ee-6, updates, javadb

I created a Java EE 6 application and implemented insert, update and delete. They work fine at times but suddenly stop working. I debugged and what I found out is that JMS messages are not passed from servlet to message-driven bean sometimes. So my data do not get inserted, updated or deleted in such cases. Is this the normal behavior of a Java EE application using persistence and javaDB? Or have I done a mistake?

In the servlet I have this:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String id=request.getParameter("id");
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String description=request.getParameter("description");
    if ((name!=null) && (description!=null)) {
        try {
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
            ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
            // here we create NewsEntity, that will be sent in JMS message
            AuthorEntity e = new AuthorEntity();
            e.setAuthorName(name);
            e.setDescription(description);
            message.setObject(e);
            messageProducer.send(message);
            messageProducer.close();
            connection.close();
            response.sendRedirect("ListAuthors");
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /*
         * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
         */
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>New Author</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>New Author</h1>");
        int n=authorEntityFacade.count();
        out.println("<form>");
        out.println("Author ID      : <input type='number' name='id' value='"+(n+1)+"'><br/>");
        out.println("Author Name    : <input type='text' name='name'><br/>");
        out.println("Description    : <textarea name='description'></textarea><br/>");
        out.println("<input type='submit'><br/>");
        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Here I prepare the jms message and send to the message-driven bean.

In message-driven bean I have:

```
@Resource
private MessageDrivenContext mdc;
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "IT11032748_Book_Catalogue-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;

public NewAuthor() {
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    ObjectMessage objectMessage=null;
    try{
        if(message instanceof ObjectMessage){
            objectMessage=(ObjectMessage)message;
            AuthorEntity author=(AuthorEntity)objectMessage.getObject();
            save(author);
        }
    }catch(JMSException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        mdc.setRollbackOnly();
    }catch(Throwable te){
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void save(Object object) {
    em.persist(object);
}
```

Here I accept the message and insert or watever.

When I debug, all values are properly set and in servlet message is also sent. But then debug point does not move to message-driven bean sometimes :(

Comment: Do you think it's normal behaviour for software to work only randomly?

Comment: @Kayaman Not abnormal with Java ;)

Comment: Btw I followed their official tutorial and created the app over 5 times and this was the best result I could get. This is what some of my fellow students also got.

Comment: What's "their official tutorial"? Tutorials can have bugs.

Comment: Here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html

Comment: tutorial is from netbeans. If they have bugs, how r we suppose to learn? Do u think u can help me with this problem?

Comment: Well, learning programming is never easy. The tutorial is probably alright though, if it's the netbeans one. Do you have proper logging? Is there a possibility that you're getting errors somewhere and ignoring them? Add a lot of logging everywhere and see if you can pinpoint the location of the problem.

Comment: I debugged my code, the problem is, JMS messages do not get sent some times. May be a netbeans configuration problem?

Comment: Maybe, if there's a configuration item called "[x] don't send JMS messages sometimes". Needs more debugging (and I don't mean running it through a debugger. That's only a part of the debugging process).